# How can I Implement recursive join using loopback self relations?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to create parent child hierarchy using self-join in strongloop. I have created model name as menu.

> menu.json

```
{
  "name": "Menu",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "MenuID": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ParentMenuID": {
      "type": "Number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {

    "menus": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Menu",
      "foreignKey": "ParentMenuID",
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

> Table data like:

```
menuId  Name     ParentID
1       parent      0
2       child       1
3      grandchild   2
```

I tried  REST API call using filter but I am getting one level of data like 
http://localhost:3000/api/Menus/?filter[include]=menus

```
 [
  {
    "MenuID": 1,
    "Name": "parent",
    "ParentMenuID": 0,
    "menus": [
      {
        "MenuID": 2,
        "Name": "child",
        "ParentMenuID": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuID": 2,
    "Name": "child",
    "ParentMenuID": 1,
    "menus": [
      {
        "MenuID": 3,
        "Name": "grandchild",
        "ParentMenuID": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuID": 3,
    "Name": "grandchild",
    "ParentMenuID": 2,
    "menus": []
  }
]
```

BUT I needed output  like:

```
[
  {
    "MenuID": 1,
    "Name": "parent",
    "ParentMenuID": 0,
    "menus": [
      {
        "MenuID": 2,
        "Name": "child",
        "ParentMenuID": 1,
        "menus": [
          {
            "MenuID": 3,
            "Name": "grandchild",
            "ParentMenuID": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please suggest any idea or example.

Answer (score 1):

After you create your model with `slc loopback:model`, just run `slc loopback:relation` and create the selfjoin as a relation.

As you now have done in your updated question. To include another you use an [include filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter), `http://localhost:3000/api/Menus/?filter[include]=menus` and to include two levels you can do like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/Menus/?filter[include][menus]=menus`

Comment: can you show small example? and how to make rest cal for this ?

Comment: You are expected to try to solve this yourself. StackOverflow is not a place where people do your work for you. Please post what you have tried so far, and what kind of problems you have with it.

Comment: I haven't  found self relation in slc loopback:relation.

Comment: Self relation is not a special type. Just use a normal relation to the same model.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am new to strongloop can you suggest any example or tutorial , I am trying to make parent child hierarchy using single model.

Comment: Read here [Creating model relations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+model+relations#Creatingmodelrelations-Usingtherelationgenerator)

Comment: I have created self join but now I am getting one level of data. how to make recursive join ?

Comment: I have updated my question please look now, how to make recursive join using loopback?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a model review, images, and the relation that you want between them is review should have multiple images. Then you have to define this relation in the json files for both the models

```
Review.json
  "relations": {
    "images": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Image",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }

Image.json
  "relations": {
    "hotelReview": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "HotelReview",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
}
```

You can also accomplish the same using `slc loopback:relation` after you create both the models.

Now in order to extract the data using this relation or join, you can use the filter api's provided by loopback, and in particular use the `include` provide by loopback.

Sample links for loopback include and filter api

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data

sample filter api, using include :-

```
localhost:3000/api/Review?filter[where][email]=xyz@abc.com&filter[include]=images
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have only single model I am trying to create self join and make parent child hierarchy, please look this link http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-self-join.php

Comment: In your examples you mentioned 2 different tables, emp1 and emp2, thats y i got confused.

Comment: Oh I am really sorry for this confusion, actually that is sql self-join concept single table consider as two table for self join. I hope you now you are getting my point can you suggest any idea ?